# Did Adam & Eve's children had to procreate among their own blood?

Tags: hebrew-bible, leviticus

According to my understanding of the Bible, the world was empty of humans before Adam and Eve.

Does it mean that their offspring had to procreate among themselves in order to populate the earth?

Why is Leviticus 18:6-18 in contradiction with what was natural at that time, which is to procreate within the same blood?

Comment: Take into consideration that Adam & Eve had near-perfect bodies after being cast out of the garden. Fast forward about 2500 years, now human bodies have degraded to the point that it needed to be prohibited.

Answer (score 2):

Does it mean that their offspring had to procreate among themselves in order to populate the earth?

Yes, a brother married his sister. Etc.

Why is Leviticus 18:6-18 in contradiction with what was natural at that time, which is to procreate within the same blood?

Leviticus happened thousands of years later. Different times, different laws.

There is even a recording of procreation from incest before Leviticus.

> Genesis 19:36 So both of Lot’s daughters became pregnant by their father. 37The older daughter had a son, and she named him Moab; he is the father of the Moabites of today. 38The younger daughter also had a son, and she named him Ben-Ammi; he is the father of the Ammonites of today.

Comment: Forthright and sensible. Up-voted +1. There is not a shred of doubt this will be asked again . . . . and again . . . .  and again . . . . .

Comment: I don't know if this is a reasonable claim. But think, it **is** mentioned on the Bible that Adam and Eve were the **first** humans but it **is not** mentioned that they were the **only** humans on Earth.

Answer (score 2):

The view of incestual ancestry based on historical common parents is founded upon misunderstanding of the ancient literature. This misconception is fuelled by popular misguided apologetic websites like CARM, see *[Where did Cain get his wife? Were there lots of people with Cain?](https://carm.org/bible-difficulties/where-did-cain-get-his-wife/)* The Genesis account of creation pertains to a spiritual or religious theme, not science; hence it is a religious literature full of parabolic, mytho-historical accounts. The interpretation that fails to see Adam Eve (Man, Woman) as figurative characters turns the text into Greek mythology. We should consider not just the historical, contextual background and details of the Genesis account but also the scientific aspect which proves that this is not how humans came into being, but through millions of years of evolution. Bad hermeneutics reduces God into a mad scientist or a mythological god. The [BioLogos](https://biologos.org/common-questions/were-adam-and-eve-historical-figures) site debunks this modern myth:

> In a common traditional view, Adam and Eve were created de novo—they were created by God as fully formed humans (Homo sapiens), roughly 6,000 to 10,000 years ago. God made them quickly and completely as fully formed humans with no biological ancestors. In this traditional de novo view, Adam and Eve are “sole progenitors”: they were the first two humans, and they alone gave rise to all other humans. The Genesis account is taken to be a record of real events similar to the way a journalist would record them today.
>
> However, some features in the biblical text suggest that there are other layers of meaning that this traditional view does not account for. Genesis 4 refers to other people (in cities, Cain’s wife) who do not seem to be descended from Adam and Eve. And some elements of Genesis 2-3 indicate that at least on some level, the text is describing Adam and Eve as archetypal figures—statements about all of us.

For those who are not keen to learn about hermeneutics and science should take the example of Job 10:8 which says, "'Your hands have framed me and fashioned me altogether, yet you destroy me", as serving the proof of creation of individual humans without interrupting the natural process of birth, as the believers believe this applies to all humans while knowing that none of us are created *de novo*.

The article presenting the facts of *[How was the Genesis Account of Creation Interpreted Before Darwin?](https://biologos.org/common-questions/how-was-the-genesis-account-of-creation-interpreted-before-darwin)* is key to understanding the evolution of hermeneutics, as it suddenly shifted into unscientific. I suspect that Martin Luther, the Protestant monk must have played a great role in this type of world-view, as he is known to be the founder of the view that faith is by definition opposed to reason, and that "reason is the devil's greatest whore". In spite of coming from a non-Jewish pagan background and having a very poor understanding of the Jewish scripture, the early Christian philosopher and apologist was informed enough to debunk the unscientific mythology loving pagan converts by presenting the literary context.

> Many people assume that Darwin’s theory must have shaken the foundations of the Christian faith because of the stark difference between evolution and the idea of a six-day creation. In truth, the literal six-day interpretation of Genesis 1–2 was not the only perspective espoused by Christian thinkers prior to the publication of The Origin of Species in 1859. The works of many early Christian theologians and philosophers reveal an interpretation of Genesis compatible with Darwin’s theory.
>
> St. Augustine of Hippo, a bishop in North Africa during the early fifth century, was another central figure of the period. Although he is widely known for Confessions, Augustine authored dozens of other works, several of which focus on Genesis 1–2.2 In The Literal Meaning of Genesis, Augustine argues that the first two chapters of Genesis are written to suit the understanding of the people at that time.3 In order to communicate in a way that all people could understand, the creation story was told in a simpler, allegorical fashion. Augustine also believed God created the world with the capacity to develop, a view that is harmonious with biological evolution.

The [Catholic](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/02089a.htm) encyclopedia states the open mindedness of Augustine concerning the Hebrew scripture, which could have only come from the Jews themselves:

> But the hermeneutics of Augustine merit great praise, especially for their insistence upon the stern law of extreme prudence in determining the meaning of Scripture: We must be on our guard against giving interpretations which are hazardous or opposed to science, and so exposing the word of God to the ridicule of unbelievers (De Genesi ad litteram, I, 19, 21, especially n. 39).

Here is another article describing lessons from [Augustine's teachings on Creation](https://biologos.org/articles/7-reasons-augustine-can-enrich-our-understanding-of-creation). The modern Christian philosopher Dr. William Lane Craig recently written a bizarre book on the [historicity of Adam](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.abl8547) which attempts to seek Adam in the evolutionary history of Sapiens; even though he has acknowledged on his site *reasonablefaith*, that the mainstream resistance to evolution is a great hurdle to the Gospel, thus proving to be the greatest enemy of Christ in the western world.

Comment: an interesting and useful take but a also too  judgmental. No one likes to be accused of adhering to a belief that is "the greatest enemy of Christ in the western world."

Answer (score 0):

Genesis gives us two descriptions of creating man.
This is the first:

> Genesis 1:27 So God created mankind in his own image,  in the image of God he
> created them; male and female he created them. 28 God blessed them and
> said to them, “Be fruitful and increase in number;

So God created man and woman, release them to the world, and told them to procreate.
The second description is the story of Adam and Eve - they were put in Eden and there was no mention about procreation. Only after eating the forbidden fruit, God is talking about the pain of giving birth:

> Genesis 3:16 To the woman he said, "I will greatly increase your pangs in childbearing; > in pain you shall bring forth children, yet your desire shall be for your husband, and
> he shall rule over you."

Base on these descriptions Adam and Eve may not be the first human creatures on earth. Their children could procreate with descendants of people from the first creation.

Comment: Most discussions on the two accounts of creation that I have heard or participated in have concluded that the two accounts are parallel accounts (viewing the matter from two different aspects) of the same creation. Your conclusion has irreconcilable discrepancies from the gospel, not the least of which is that it disagrees with all of Paul's teaching concerning Adam, sin, death and the death of Christ.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning there was nothing. God created a beginning. After his creation of the world, he created
man and women.  I believe no one else exist. So the answer is brother and sister would mix blood.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If we take the Genesis account as historically factual, it is hard to escape the idea that Adam's children married each other. The one "out" for this conclusion is this:

> Then Cain went out from the presence of the Lord, and settled in the
> land of Nod, east of Eden. Cain had relations with his wife and she
> conceived, and gave birth to Enoch; and he built a city, and called
> the name of the city Enoch, after the name of his son. (Gen. 4:16-17)

This passage was used to powerful effect by Clarence Darrow against William Jennings Bryant at the famous ["Scope Monkey Trial:"](https://pastorbriantubbs.com/how-cain-got-a-wife/)

```
DARROW: Did you ever discover where Cain got his wife?
BRYAN: No sir, I leave the agnostics to hunt for her.
DARROW: You have never found out?
BRYAN: I have never tried to find.
DARROW: You have never tried to find?
BRYAN: No.
DARROW: The Bible says he got one, doesn’t it?  Were there other people on earth...?
BRYAN: I cannot say.
DARROW: You cannot say? Did that never enter your consideration?
BRYAN: Never bothered me.
DARROW: There were no others recorded... Where she came from, you don’t know. All right.
```

Some interpret this passage to mean that Cain found a wife in the land of Nod, which implies other human beings already existed there. One way of understanding this is to see Adam and Eve as spiritually different from other humans, but still of the same species. In this view Adam was not literally molded from clay or earth, but was symbolically molded by God through an evolutionary process (or Intelligent Design).
Traditionalists understand Cain to have brought his wife (who was also his sister) with him when he fled from Eden. In other words, Cain did not meet his wife in Nod, but only "knew her" there in the sense of having sexual intercourse and bearing children.

**The OP also asks "Why is Leviticus 18:6-18 in contradiction with what was natural at that time, which is to procreate within the same blood?"** The answer is that this rule was given to the Israelites after Moses and was not in force in Adam's time. Whether or not Cain and Seth had children with their sisters, this law simply did not apply to them. The same is true for many other Levitical rules designed. A particularly relevant example is that Israelites after Moses could not marry outsiders. But but prior to this they were allowed to do so: Judah married a Canaanite, Joseph married and Egyptian, and even Moses himself married a Midian and/or a Cushite.

**Conclusion: Some interpreters hold that Cain and Seth did not marry their sisters, because - although their parents were the first humans in a spiritual sense - they were part of a wider proto-human species. But since this view contradicts the idea the Adam and Eve were the first and only human beings, it is hard to reconcile this theory with the text as literally understood. Leviticus did not yet apply in any case.**